# Как вывести массив данных с помощью smarty?

Tags: массивы, smarty

Приветствую, такой вопрос: как вывести массив данных с помощью `smarty`?
На PHP как бы всё легко и просто.

```
while ($my = mysql_fetch_array ($array)) {
    $i++; 
    $title[$i]=$my['title']
    $content[$i]=$my['content']
}
```

А вот как я пробовала реализовать на смарти

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE author='".$go."' LIMIT 1");
 $rows=array();
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
   $rows[]=$row;
 }
$smarty->assign('data',$rows);
```

Ну и в самом *tpl уже так

```
{foreach from=$data item=item}
   <p>{$item.title}</p>
{/foreach}
```

А в итоге, выводится лишь одна первая, из двух, записей.
Что я не так сделала?

Comment: Спасибо)) Оформите пожалуйста ответом) я вам плюсану)

Comment: Без проблем xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так думаю, что "LIMIT 1" в запросе явно лишний.